# Data slice across identical-format CSVs?

Tags: csv, spreadsheet, slice

What is a good programmatic (and Open Source) way to extract data from the same cell across a set of identically formatted spreadsheets.

The data would be something like this...

Month1.csv:

```
Data type, value
Monthly expenses, 1000.30
```

Month2.csv:

```
Data type, value
Monthly expenses, 1050.00
```

Month3.csv:

```
Data type, value
Monthly expenses, 2010.55
```

...and would give output like this:

YearSummary.csv:

```
Monthly expenses
1000.30
1050.00
2010.55
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use awk like this:

```
awk -F, 'FNR>1{print $2}' Month*.csv > YearSummary
```

That says, look at all Month*.csv files and, if not the first line (which is  a column header), print the second field, using a comma as separator.

Or, if you really, really want the header:

```
echo Monthly Expenses > YearSummary
awk -F, 'FNR>1{print $2}' Month*.csv >> YearSummary
```